# Suggestions for GR solved problems books

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

Study Topic: General Relativity

I'm looking for a recommendation for either a dedicated problems and solved solutions book or, failing that, a textbook with a separate comprehensive solutions manual.

Searched Amazon, nearest I could see was Schaum on Tensors, which I have already, also I have Relativity Demystified, which is excellent for practice but does not cover say cosmological topics in much depth.

Or a GR professional's home page or blog with solutions would be great. But books are my first choice, less distracting than online imo.

Comment: [I think this one is quite well-known](http://www.amazon.com/Relativity-Demystified-David-McMahon/dp/0071455450)

Comment: @Danu thanks very much for the quick answer Danu, that's a terrific practice book, which I already have,  sorry, I should said that. I'd be lost without it,  it's just that he covers solutions using 2-forms,(which is fine) but I need practice on other approaches, also he rushes through cosmological concepts.

Comment: [Problem Book in Relativity and Gravitation](http://www.nrbook.com/relativity/) is quite well-known and comprehensive, and it has the virtue that it is available free and legally online.

Comment: @JohnnyMo1  Brilliant, slight panic when I could only see problems, but solutions as well, thank you very much.

Comment: @AcidJazz if you can read italian then try http://www.amazon.com/Esercizi-relativit%C3%A0-generale-Giovanni-Fernando/dp/8833957837

Comment: [Lightman](http://www.amazon.com/Problem-Book-Relativity-Gravitation-Lightman/dp/069108162X) is pretty good, although there are no "warm-up" problems.

Comment: @JohnnyMo1 That link no longer works. Do you know of another site to download the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested to have a look at the the site [The Universe in Problems](http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Main_Page).

This is a community maintained web site, so the problems are very variable in style and difficulty. The downside of this is that many of the problems will not suit your current level of expertise, but on the other hand the upside is that there is bound to be some fraction of the problems that is appropriate.

I personally find it easy to resist the lure of doing worked exercises, but I have found the site a useful source of information for all sorts of things relativistic.

Comment: Thanks very much John, personally speaking I absolutely NEED the practice, without it I only gain a superficial understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for solution manuals too. Here's fruits of my endeavor.

[Problem Book in Relativity and Gravitation](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691177786/problem-book-in-relativity-and-gravitation):
This is a really well written book. It builds up gently and while does not touch every topic in GR it does do justice to the one's it does touch.

[The General Theory of Relativity](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/general-theory-of-relativity/851FC27F0490300918EEBEEC4380B0D1):
I personally found this book quite fast paced but on the other hand it touches a lot of topics (for example the Raychaudhuri equations). I think my GR is a bit weak so perhaps this would be useful to the advanced practioner.

[McGill University Questions and Partial Solutions](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Erhb/ph514/): This is a gold mine of problems and solutions. I'm personally not sure why they have written partial besides the solution since I think one can follow them. The course outline [here](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Erhb/ph514/outline4.pdf). It closely follows [Caroll](https://www.amazon.in/Spacetime-Geometry-Introduction-General-Relativity/dp/1108488390) and also tells the relevant sections in each assignment.

[Universitetet i Oslo](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS4160/v22/): While this is a Norwegian university it's questions and solutions are thankfully in English. It seems to be extensively written with $14$ problem sets. The course outline is [here](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS4160/v22/organizer.pdf).

Comment: Cosmology and Astrophysics through Problems is also a good book btw